# Error connecting to MySQL database remotely

Tags: mysql, networking, mysql-error-2003

I have a MySQL database which I would like to connect to from a remote machine. I have commented out bind-address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to allow remote connections. Locally on the machine I can now log in to MySQL

```
mysql --host=[SERVER_IP] --user=[USER] --password=[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```

which works fine. I cannot, however, log in from my laptop. Here I get an error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on [SERVER_IP] (110)
```

when I run the same command as above. I can ping the server

```
64 bytes from [SERVER_IP]: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.367 ms
```

without any errors. I can also traceroute

```
1  * * *
```

without any errors. Finally, I have run nmap with the following result:

```
3306/tcp open mysql
```

which would indicate that this is not a firewall issue.

Does anybody have any idea of whats going on? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I have also given the user access rights:

```
 GRANT ALL ON [DB_NAME].* to '[USER]'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]'
```

Sorry about that!

Comment: Does the user you are connecting with have permissions to connect from any host, or is it restricted to localhost only?

Comment: You can ping, but can you `telnet YOUR_SERVER_IP_OR_HOSTNAME 3306`?

Comment: I have run

    GRANT ALL ON [DB_NAME].* to '[USER]'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[PASSWORD]';

I forgot to mention that in the post, actually. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Thomas check if your comp can be connected to, via the inter net

Comment: I cannot telnet. At least I get no response from the server. Do you think it is a firewall issue?

Comment: @Thomas can you please give me the code that is wrong

Comment: @Thomas check the last point of my answer

Comment: The code is essentially in my first post. I run the mysql command with the host, username and password parameters to connect to the database on the server.

Comment: OK another potential issue could be that your laptop firewall is not letting the mysql application through

Comment: packets are filtered away by router, firewall, etc. Network problem. It's a rare case that you have to connect to remote MySQL server, as this makes security problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities:

- you dont have permissions to use the file from different computers
- the file is not accessible
- you can't connect to the host
- user/pass doesn't have permissions on the other computer
- if you say you get no response from the server, that is your problem, your server is not responding. aka it isn't online

Comment: But the user/pass should be mysql specific, right? They do not have anything to do with the user/pass of the underlying operating system.

Comment: @Thomas yes, but to access the computer you need a user/pass right? anyway, as you say, you get no response from the server, which means that your server is not responding.. can you please give me your code?

Comment: Check my other answer.